# Ruby, Array, Object - Select Object

Tags: ruby, arrays, search, object

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
class OReport
   attr_accessor :id, :name
   def initialize(id, name, desc)
      @id       = id
      @name     = name
      @desc     = desc
   end
end

reports = Array.new
reports << OReport.new(1, 'One', 'One Desc')
reports << OReport.new(2, 'Two', 'Two Desc')
reports << OReport.new(3, 'Three', 'Three Desc')
```

How do I now search "Reports" for 2, so that I can extract name and description from it?

Comment: report = reports.select{|r| e.name == 1}.name

Comment: you're missing an attr_accessor for description though,.

Comment: oops, true, my select would raise an horrible error :) -sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the primary use for `reports` is to retrieve by id, then consider using a hash instead:

```
reports = {}
reports[1] = OReport.new(1, 'One', 'One Desc')
reports[2] = OReport.new(2, 'Two', 'Two Desc')
reports[3] = OReport.new(3, 'Three', 'Three Desc')

p reports[2].name    # => "Two"
```

Hash lookup is usually faster than array lookup, but more important, it's simpler.

Comment: Never thought of using the reports[x] setup. Easy and simple.

Comment: In such cases, is it better to remove `@id` from `OReport` instance and use `reports.key(report)` when you need to refer an id, or is it better to leave it as in your answer?

Comment: @sawa, If an instance of OReport needs to know its ID for some purpose, then it must retain it.  Otherwise, the ID can be kept solely as a hash key, if desired.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to get an object from a collection given a condition:

```
reports.find { |report| report.id == 2 }
#=> => #<OReport:0x007fa32c9e85c8 @desc="Two Desc", @id=2, @name="Two">
```

If you expect more than one object to meet the condition, and want all of them instead of the first matching one, use [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select).

Comment: I like it, but Wayne's answer is easier and everything is based on the ID, so will be faster and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

You can get reports for 2 by the following syntax.

```
reports[1].name
reports[1].id
```

it will surely work for you.

Comment: What if they're added to the array in a different order?